# How do you change the prompt of your terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, settings

right now my terminal reads Sean:~ A2014$ and I don't understand how to change it so it doesn't say Sean. Is there a general terminal name or are they relative based off of your system?

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you're referring to the prompt? (Next to where you input commands in the terminal). If you want to change the title of the window, i think you can go to Shell>Edit title in the top bar while terminal is open.

On MacOS you should be able to edit/create a file in ~ (The home directory) called .bash_profile. In this file you can change (or add if it's not there) `export PS1="{settings}"` where {settings} is what will show up as the terminal prompt.

You can do this with a text editor like nano;
In a terminal you would type `cd ~` and then
`nano .bash_profile` to create/edit it. Just make sure not to edit any PATH variables!

There are a bunch of bash prompt flags to display things like time and computer name you can look up, but you can just use plaintext as the prompt if you like. (A single $ is pretty common)